# How to disable scroll parent component when child page (popup page) is opened? - CSS

Tags: reactjs, css

I am working on a React Demo Project. I have a parent page and a child page.

I need to disable scroll on the parent page when the child page is opened. This is my Demo [Fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/046w69y330)

This is my Code

```
        <div className="overlay">
        <div className="overlay-opacity" onClick={this.hideChild} />
        <Child data={data} applyFilter={this.applyFilter} />
      </div>
```

Comment: You need to provide more details to explain your issue, what do you mean with `parent page` and `child page`? how should the behave? what's their behavior now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the popup is opened, add a class to the parent that will disable the scrolling via CSS with `overflow: hidden`

When closing the popup, remove that class. You can store a variable in the state of the parent that will track if the popup is opened or not, and add / remove the class depending on that variable.

Comment: Just add an overflow: hidden to your .parent-overlay class in the CSS and you should get the correct behavior since you're already adding a class when opening the popup.

Comment: Can you kindly fork and show in my demo fiddle ? I did but that is not working

Answer (score 0):

you're already adding a class to the parent when a child is opened. 
you can prevent scrolling using css, e.g.

```
.parent-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

this should do the trick, see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/mjz1jk79q8

However, there might be a less view manipulative variant in order to achieve this too.